# Problems with Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, kubuntu, atheros

Here is my problem:

### lspci:

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

### lshw -C network

```
*-network  DISPONIBLE  

   descrição: Interface sem fio
   produto: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
   fabricante: Qualcomm Atheros
   ID físico: 0
   informações do barramento: pci@0000:01:00.0
   versão: 01
   serial: 1c:c6:3c:ce:49:e3
   largura: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuração: latency=0
```

Note that the wireless interface has no logic name. So, after this step nothing works with wireless connection.

I am running kubuntu 14.04.2 lts

### uname -a

Linux jazzbass 3.16.0-36-generic #48~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 15 13:11:28 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Does it get a logical name, ideally wlan0, if you load the driver? `sudo modprobe ath9k` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: Hello, chili555.

Comment: Thank you. No. Load the driver don't get a logical name to device. The problem is on the boot. If get a logical name on the boot, the device run fine. If don't get a logical name on the boot, nothing works.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with the same hardware. Have you ever solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the driver to load automatically on boot. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo ath9k  >>  /etc/modules
exit
```

Reboot. Check:

```
iwconfig
dmesg | grep ath
```

Please post the result here and let us have the link in your reply. http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Ok. I will do. But, sometimes, the hardware works fine, doing nothing.  After upgrade the kernel to 3.16.0-37-generic (about one week), all it's ok with the hardware and the driver.

Comment: I prefer to observe what will happen in the coming days. If driver run fine or not with the new kernel. I will coment here. Thank you.

Comment: Important to coment: the computer is new. I bought a month ago, AMD kabini. I think the hardware it's ok.